# 500 Error when trying to define path to parent directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, question2answer

I am trying to integrate Wordpress with [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/) so that they both use the same database for users. The [instructions for doing this](http://www.question2answer.org/wordpress.php) are pretty straight-forward. All I need to do is define the directory for my Wordpress installation in the Question2Answer config file. Unfortunately, no matter how I define the path to the Wordpress directory, I get a 500 error.

The urls for the installations are:

**Wordpress:** http://stage.example.com

**Question2Answer:** http://stage.example.com/ask

The directory structure is

> **Wordpress:** public_html/stage
>
> **Question2Answer:** public_html/stage/ask

Definition:

```
define('QA_WORDPRESS_INTEGRATE_PATH', '../');
```

I've tried 100 different ways to define the path to the Wordpress directory in my Question2Answer config file and I keep getting a `500 error`. I'm fairly certain that I am defining the path to the directory correctly so I think it must be some sort of permissions or .htaccess problem but I'm not sure what it could be. Any ideas?

Here is the error:

`PHP Question2Answer fatal error: Could not find wp-load.php file for WordPress integration - please check QA_WORDPRESS_INTEGRATE_PATH in qa-config.php`

Comment: What does your error logs say is generating the 500 error?

Comment: I copied the error in above. It says that it couldn't find the wp-load.php file. But that doesn't make any sense because when I echo the path, it is correct.

Comment: so you are trying to define a constant variable which represents a cd type of shell command to move down one directory with the `../`

Comment: I've tried it many, many, different ways. I also used $_SERVER variables and the full path.

Comment: have you gone to your main wordpress directory which is like public_html or something and issued the `pwd` command? Maybe what this prints out is what you should put in your `define` function.

Comment: Yes - I copied and pasted it in.

Comment: Which directory contains *wp-load.php.* ?

Comment: So its in a subdomain (http://stage.mydomain.com) that is located in public_html/stage. The Question2Answer is installed in a normal directory inside that subdomain.

Comment: You have the correct version *WordPress 3.x* ?

Comment: The instructions specify to give the full path so this is probably the absolute path that is not dependent on where the file this function is written in is stored. So it would be something like `define('QA_WORDPRESS_INTEGRATE_PATH', /Full/path/to/directory/where-this-is/wp-load.php);`

Comment: That is what I am using (I think). I used  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; to figure that out and then I plugged it in. If the path is incorrect, the script echos an error. If I plug in the correct path, I get a 500 error and it writes to the error log.

Comment: Stage is a password protected directory, would that effect anything?

Comment: The log for the 500 error says that the server cannot find the file though correct? I would find the file on the server, then issue the `pwd` command and copy and paste this path in your text editor to plug-in to the `define` function. Probably ask your web-host too what is wrong with the server. :D

Comment: Yep, thats what I did. I will contact my host I guess.

Comment: Sorry I could not help more. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be silly, but keep in mind that the whole `define('QA_WORDPRESS_INTEGRATE_PATH', '/PATH/WORDPRESS/');` **is** in a comment line. So you have to put the `*/` before the `define` line.

I was also struggling a lot, until I saw [this post](http://www.question2answer.org/qa/15400/how-to-specify-the-path-to-the-wordpress)